# Reverse Geo with Algolia

Tags: algolia, reverse-geocoding

Does Algolia provide a reverse geocoding like [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) or [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)? I.e. find address from lat/lng?

I didn't find anything in the Algolia Places doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their doc https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html#api-options-type you can get any the following types:

```
-city
-country
-address
-busStop
-trainStation
-townhall
-airport
```

The do return quite a bit of data with their reverse geocoding API:

```
curl -X POST 'https://places-dsn.algolia.net/1/places/query' --data '{"aroundLatLng": "48.876599,2.124843"}'
```

Sometimes too little data can be a problem, as can be too much data. You'll have to sort through it yourself.

With a lot of players in the reverse geocoding API field these days, it will all depend on what type of data you want to get back.

If you just want one matching address and a couple of nearby streets try:

```
curl 'https://geocode.xyz/48.876599,2.124843?geoit=json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since recently, you can use directly the `/reverse` endpoint like this:

`curl -X GET 'https://places-dsn.algolia.net/1/places/reverse?hitsPerPage=1&aroundLatLng=48.876599,2.124843'`

See more info in the documentation: https://community.algolia.com/places/rest.html#reverse-geocoding